# error 1064 in trigger mysql

Tags: mysql

This is my first time using mysql and I am tying to learn how to use trigger.

Im using navicat, i go to table design and then go triggers tab. I create a trigger named testing and in definition I typed:

```
delimiter |
  CREATE TRIGGER lpr.mytesting AFTER INSERT ON lpr.lpr_opt_upload 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      set new.lpr_text := reverse(new.lpr_text);
    END;
| delimiter ;
```

All im tying to do is whenever something new is inserted, I reverse the text in lpr_text field. However, i get "1064 - you have an error in your SQL; check the manual that corresponds o your MySql server version for the right syntax to yse 'ON lpr_opt_upload' FOR EACH ROW create trigger testing before insert on lpr_op' at line 1." I dont understand what Im doing wrong, I am just copying an trigger example.

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//

I figured out the problem. I am using navicat and in navicat trigger tab, you only type the body into the definition, Not the header (ex: CREATE TRIGGER lpr.mytesting AFTER INSERT ON lpr.lpr_opt_upload). There are check box next to the name of your trigger and you use those instead of writing your own header.

Answer (score 1):

The `DELIMITER` command is a client command, which not all clients support (it doesn't get sent to the server at all, it just instructs the client how to tell statements apart in order that they get sent to the server correctly).  References to it in the MySQL manual assume that you are using the 'official' MySQL clients, such as the `mysql` command-line tool or MySQL Workbench (both of which support the `DELIMITER` command).

I don't know how to change the statement delimiter in Navicat, but that is the root of your problem.